# Calculate percentage based on two fields, one of which is an embedded view

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to calculate a percentage based on two fields in my table. I am using views and I have a table which has 2 fields, one field is an aggregation of of all records and the other is an embedded view which has another number - I used the Views Field View module for embedding the field.

How can i get a percentage between these 2 fields. The Math Expression field is not supported in drupal 8 and I have also tried the views_simple_math_field and it didn't help me at all. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried in output code:

```
<?php 
echo count($row->field_a) + count($row->field_a) ;
?>
```

and the result is:
[image]

I modified the view, and used aggregation.

[image]

I modified the field a:

[image]

I modified the field b:

[image]

I modified the field php:

[image]

And the code:

[image]

And result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you want ***sum*** two field, you install the module: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php

As an example, add two fields in your content "***basic pages***":

1. field_a
2. field_b

[image]
I create a content of example: nid = 43

[image]

Please create a new view as is the image.
[image]

in your field "**Global: PHP (php)**"
in the section: "**Output code**".

sum two fields please use the following code

```
<?php 
echo $row->field_a +$row->field_a ;
?>
```

[image]

preview

[image]

Comment: Thamk you very much for your response, But my fields are aggregated as COUNT so its not working