# Computed field: sum fields from different content type

Tags: entities

I use the module "computed field".

How can I calculate (sum) the value from one field in one content type and a field from other content type? Is it possible?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: How are the two content types connected?  If you have an Entity Reference or Relation that links them, this is pretty easy.  If not, it might be very hard.

Comment: they connected by taxonomy term.

Comment: If they are not connected directly, you need to give more information.  The computed field is on a node of content type ABC.  How many other nodes need to be considered?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by querying database :

```
<?php
$database = \Drupal::service('database');

$database->select('node_<FIELD>', 'n');
$database->fields('n', ['bundle']);
$database->addExpression('SUM(n.<FIELD>_value)', 'sum');
$database->groupBy('n.bundle');
$results = $database->execute();

foreach($results->fetchAll() as $result){
    print $result->bundle.' : '.$result->sum;
}
```

This example is for node, but quiet similar with taxonomy or other entity type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one view and add your fields. Then review the following [response](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249956/79504):
Or the following [response](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249908/79504)